# Firebase functions: Deploy only newly added functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I happen to have over 100 cloud functions. I occasionally add new sets of functions to it. Is there a sort of flag that can deploy newly added set of functions only? Eg

```
firebase deploy --only functions --new
```

PS: I know I can specify the newly added functions to be deployed in the command. However most times it is hard to track the new functions and all I want to do is deploy newly added functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a flag is not available in the CLI.

You could maybe take advantage of the option that allows grouping functions into export groups in your `/functions/index.js` file. Grouping functions allows you to deploy multiple functions using a single command. In other words, you would create a new group for each set of new functions. See the [CLI Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions) for more details.